# android preferred button size

Tags: android

what is the the preferred android button size from usability perspective.
I suppose it should be in dp,
I have tried several different size from 50dp to 30dp, each time it looks a little odd, what's the general size used in different android application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like there is no standard way or , perhaps none documented , I ended up with 40dp

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your layout for buttons

```
style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
```

This are the standard buttons per say.
Hope it helps

Comment: I am using imageview for buttons sometimes, so I am not sure this would work

Comment: it seems like there is no agreed value, I decided to go 40dp all out.